# Python Panda function to summarize the total rows of a group

Tags: python, r, pandas

i have a dataset with many columns, and i want to summarize the total rows for each country. i grouped by the data by country and tried by count function and plot it. but the result has shown all columns for each country. i want a summary for each country to be shown on the graph bar, with one line or dot.
i want something like the R function - summarize(Total = n()).

thats my method on python:

```
newData = myData.groupby('Country').count();
newData.plot(kind='bar',  figsize=(15, 10))
```

Comment: Try this: `myData.groupby('Country')['somrandomcolumn'].count()`

Comment: similar to summarise in R is the aggregate function: `myData.groupby('Country').aggregate({'Country':'count'})`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for the basic count per country:

```
newData = df.groupby('Country').apply(lambda x: len(x))    
newData.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15, 10))
```